# Scraping of data with scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from the following link https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/archive/year-2018,month-1.cms. Specifically, I am trying to take the URLs present inside the calendar table.
My current code for doing this is

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="calender"]//a/@href').extract()
```

But this gives me no results. Where am I going wrong and what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the page's source, you'll see that the links you're trying to extract do not exist.
Instead, there is a block of javascript that generates them.

You have two possibilities for scraping this data:

- Figure out what the js code does and do it with your python code
  instead
- Get something (e.g. a browser) to execute the js code and
  give you the resulting html

Comment: So is there any way to automate such a task? I mean can I write something so that whenever my crawler comes across such a situation(even on a different webpage), it is able to tackle it.

Comment: There is if you go with the second option. There are lots of possibilities, but using scrapy-splash is probably simplest.